# Method overload with function parameter returning Ambiguous method call error

Tags: java

I have two overload method and a test method

```
<T, R> R ifNotEmpty(T o, Function<T, R> function)
<T> void ifNotEmpty(T o, Consumer<T> consumer)
void test(String) {
//do nothing
}
```

when I call

```
ifNotEmpty("aaa", x -> test(x));
```

I get an error

```
Ambiguous method call. Both
ifNotEmpty(String,Function<String, R>) and
ifNotEmpty(String,Consumer<String>) match
```

Why?

And when I write like this,it's correct

```
ifNotEmpty("aaa", this::test);
```

like this also correct

```
ifNotEmpty("aaa", (String x) -> test(x));
```

Why?

I used JDK-1.8 and IDEA-2017.3.5-community edition

Comment: So it's a jdk problem? But I also curious why the later two style are correct